# Showing $\sin(z)$ is elliptic via conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, periodic-functions, conformal-geometry

One could use Euler's identity to show that $\sin(z)$ is an elliptic function, however, if we define the $\arcsin(z)$ as

$$\arcsin(z) = \int_0^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-w^2}}dw$$

we would like to show that this is a conformal map, mapping the upper half-plane to a triangle (where one of the points of the triangle is the point of infinity, so this triangle will look like an infinite parallel strip). Then from we make use of the Schwarz reflection principle, and then note that $\sin(z)$ is the inverse map.

My issue is showing why this is a conformal map from the upper half-plane to the triangle.

Comment: What's causing you problems, showing “conformal” or showing “to the triangle”?

Comment: @HansLundmark Showing that is maps the upper half-plane to the triangle.

Comment: Where does it send $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ ? Where does it send $\mathbb{R} $ ? Where does it send $|z| = r, Im(z) > 0$ ?

Comment: This is a Schwarz–Christoffel mapping for a polygon with two interior angles equal to $\pi/2$.